# Help to understand content type

Tags: content-type, list-definition, custom-field-types, field-definition

Given the below definition of a content type:

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Algorithm Types List Definition"  EnableContentTypes="TRUE"  FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/AlgorithmTypesListDefinition" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <MetaData>
       <ContentTypes>
           <ContentType ID="0x010077bed2b1dce44a12a759eeca0717f322"
             Name="AlgorithmType"
             Inherits="TRUE">
                <FieldRefs>

                    <FieldRef Name="StartDate" ID="9ea1256f-6b67-43b0-8ab7-1d643bf8a834"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="EndDate" ID="900503fa-4ab1-4938-be75-b40694ab97b6"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Comments"   ID="240a28ee-78ff-446b-93fd-c56ba45debc8" />
    </FieldRefs>

  </ContentType>
```

Can FieldRef elements point to List Columns defined inside the enclosing List Definitions or do ContentTypes always have to be based on Site Columns.

If that is true:
Can content type defined inline at the List Definition level contain FieldRefs that point to both Site Columns and current List Template definition fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First question: Yes they can
Second: yes

see: [image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543680%28v=office.12%29.aspx)